# process does not log when run as background

Tags: shell, docker, process, sh, ash

I want to run this command inside a docker container ( `ubuntu:18.04` image ):

```
(cd inse/; sh start.sh > log.txt 2>&1 ;) &
```

but when I run it, it does not log it to `log.txt`. When I run it this way:

```
(cd inse/; sh start.sh > log.txt 2>&1 ;)
```

It locks the forground (as it should do) and when I kill it I see that the `log.txt` file is filled with log stuff, which means It works correctly.

Why is this behaviour happening?

The contents of `start.sh` is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. venv/bin/activate;
python3 main.py;
```

#### UPDATE:

Actually this command is not the entry point of container and I run it inside another shell but inside a long running container (testing container).

Using with nohup, no success:

```
(cd inse/; nohup sh start.sh | tee log.txt;) &
```

I think this problem refers to using `()` the subshell concept inside `sh`. It seems it does not let output go anywhere when ran in background.

#### UPDATE 2:

Even this does not work:

```
sh -c "cd inse/; sh start.sh > log.txt 2>&1 &"
```

#### UPDATE 3:

Not even this:

```
sh -c "cd inse/; sh start.sh > log.txt 2>&1;" &
```

Comment: Can you try and run this with "nohup"? This should keep it running and prevent  the container from stopping

Comment: Usually you wouldn’t do any of this: you’d create a custom image that `COPY` your application code in, and set its `CMD ["python3", "main.py"]`.  `docker run` will start the service without you manually doing things.  Don’t create a virtual environment, Docker provides that isolation for you.

Comment: check the update please.

Comment: I think the process becomes orphaned and thats the reason behind all this problems. What do you think?

Comment: @asdfg_rocks first you should get read of the "cd": either call start.sh with whole path or something else. That because "nohup" should be called on all the command. In any case you are trying to solve a problem that you shouldn't even try to solve. To explain myself: it is a bad practise to generate log files inside the container. Log messages should be written to standard output and picked up by the log driver registered for the container.

Comment: Is the process being stopped due to reading from stdin? If so you can use `(cd inse/; sh start.sh > log.txt 2>&1 ;) < /dev/null &`

Comment: the process is not stopped and it is running but its log is not going to file and it is going nowhere (neither showing in `docker logs` neither inside `log.txt`).

Answer (score 2):

I found what was causing the problem.
It was buffered python output. This problem is caused by python.

I should have used python unbuffered output:

```
python -u blahblah
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this command and please check that have full access to that folder where log.txt is created.use CMD/RUN step in Dockerfile to run start.sh.

CMD /inse/start.sh > log.txt 2>&1 ;

**OR**

RUN /inse/start.sh > log.txt 2>&1 ;

Comment: definitely in this case it works. The problem is when I use subshells inside a shell to do this.